# i need to find all permutations of a list

Tags: python

I need to find all permutations of a inputted 4 digit number by a user

I have tried you use itertools.permutation but it is not working and I can only use pre set lists to make the code work

```
import itertools
NumInput = str(input('Type here: '))
magicList = list(NumInput)
itertools.permutations(magicList)
print(magicList)
```

I hoped that the itertools.permutation would print all possible perms but it does not. I need the code to print all possible combinations of the inputted 4 digit number but I don't know how

Comment: you never assigned the result of `itertools.permutations(magicList)` !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct: `itertools.permutations` is a *function* that returns an *iterator*, but does not print anything. Hence, it is your job to get the output and print it, like so:

```
# get the itertools.combinations iterator
perms = itertools.permutations(magicList) 
# convert to a list
perms = list(perms)
# print it
print(perms)
```

result:

```
[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('1', '2', '4', '3'), ...
```